# H5BP & 1140 Grid scripts

Tags: css, grid, html5boilerplate

I'm working on combining the 1140px Grid System (http://cssgrid.net/) with HTML5Boilerplate (http://html5boilerplate.com/), attempting to combine the best of both as the starting point for my own framework for projects.

As I don't know any JavaScript, can anyone tell me if the version of the Modernizr script built into HTML5Boilerplate covers the same function as the script which the 1140px Grid System uses to enable media queries in some unsupported browsers, or do I need to include both?

Here's a link to the info about both:

http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/
http://modernizr.com/download/

Any ideas? I've had a look in the modernizr documentation but it's a bit beyond me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know any JavaScript don't go with Modernizr (and start learning JavaScript a soon as you can). [CSS3-mediaquery-js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/) is easier to use, as you only have to add the media queries to your css files and forget about any JS. If you want to go with [HTML5 BP](http://html5boilerplate.com) anyway, I recommend you to forget about [1140](http://cssgrid.net/) and go with [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/)

**Update:**
[Respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) would be an alternative to [CSS3-mediaqueries-js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/). Again, the later could be the easiest to use.